# Type Mismatch Error on Range in For Each loop

Tags: excel, vba, range, type-mismatch

I would like to use an entire column as my range for my code, but I keep running to Type Mismatch error, This is my Code.

```
            Dim xRgDate As Range
            Dim xCellDate As Range
            Set xRgDate = Range("E:E")
            For Each xCellDate In xRgDate
                If Not IsEmpty(xCellDate) Then
                    xMonth = Month(xCellDate.Value)
                    xMonthName = MonthName(xMonth)
                    If Len(Dir((FPath & "\" & ws.Name & "\" & xMonthName), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                    MkDir (FPath & "\" & ws.Name & "\" & xMonthName)
                    End If
                End If
            Next xCellDate
```

I keep trying to change the Range Selection, for example this works but it's not the entire column

```
 Set xRgDate = Range("E9:E40")
```

This is the full code

```
Sub SplitEachMonthToSubFodlers()

    Dim FPath As String
    FPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If Len(Dir((FPath & "\" & ws.Name), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir (FPath & "\" & ws.Name)
            
            Dim xRgDate As Range
            Dim xCellDate As Range
            Set xRgDate = ws.Range("E9:E40")
            For Each xCellDate In xRgDate
                If Not IsEmpty(xCellDate) Then
                    xMonth = Month(xCellDate.Value)
                    xMonthName = MonthName(xMonth)
                    If Len(Dir((FPath & "\" & ws.Name & "\" & xMonthName), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
                    MkDir (FPath & "\" & ws.Name & "\" & xMonthName)
                    End If
                End If
            Next xCellDate
        Else
        MsgBox ("Folders Already Existed")
        End If
    Next ws
    MsgBox ("Folders Created")
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line do you get the error on? how did you declare (Dim) xMonth, XMonthName, FPath, what is in FPath (DIR wouldn't work with UNC paths), ws?

Comment: I have just edited the question to include the full code, please advice, the error occurs in the  Set xRgDate = Range("E:E") line as i will get type mismatch error, but if i change the code to Set xRgDate = Range("E9:E40"), it works but not as intended

Comment: My goal is to not only have E9:E40 as my range but the entire E Column as my range

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `set xRgDate=ws.Range("E:E")` (or the outer loop), your error must be originating on a different line (although I wouldn't iterate over 1 million cells).

Comment: Hmm, I Tried Debugging it again, and it seems the type mismatch error was found in Month = Month(xCellDate.Value)
xMonthName = MonthName(xMonth)
But it works when I set E9:E40 as my range, any advices ?

Comment: yes, when you use the entire column there are probably cells which are considered 'Not IsEmpty` but have no valid date. When you debug, and hit the error (in break mode), type `? ws.name, xCellDate.Address` on the immediate window and check the value in that cell

Comment: Btw, using ` Set xRgDate = ws.Range("E:E").Resize(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count)` could prevent looping over 1 million cells for each sheet.

Comment: `Set xRgDate = ws.UsedRange.Columns("E")` gives the same result @tinazmu

Comment: If you use `For Each xCellDate In xRgDate` then xCellDate is a range, not a single cell; then Month may fail on a range; use `For Each xCellDate In xRgDate.Cells`, instead

Comment: Thanks, I just found out the solution to the problem. And yes just like you said there was a problem on the data.

Comment: Thank you for the advice and suggestions, I will try implementing it on my code. @tinazmu

Comment: Thank you too for the advice and suggestions, I will try implementing it on my code @Black Cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Create Monthly Subfolders

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateMonthlySubFolders()
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Create Monthly Subfolders"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const FIRST_CELL As String = "E9"
     
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim pSep As String: pSep = Application.PathSeparator
    Dim FolderPath As String: FolderPath = wb.Path & pSep
    
    If Len(FolderPath) = 1 Then
        MsgBox "The file """ & wb.Name & """ hasn't been saved yet.", _
            vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rg As Range
    Dim Data(), cValue, fCount As Long, rCount As Long, r As Long
    Dim SubPathLevel1 As String, SubPathLevel2 As String, MonthString As String
    
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        
        SubPathLevel1 = FolderPath & ws.Name
        If Len(Dir(SubPathLevel1, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then ' doesn't exist
           MkDir SubPathLevel1
           fCount = fCount + 1
        'Else ' the folder already exists; do nothing
        End If
        
        With ws.Range(FIRST_CELL)
            Set rg = Intersect(.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), ws.UsedRange)
        End With
        
        If Not rg Is Nothing Then ' the column range is not empty
            rCount = rg.Rows.Count
            If rCount = 1 Then
                ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
            Else
                Data = rg.Value
            End If
            For r = 1 To rCount
                cValue = Data(r, 1)
                If IsDate(cValue) Then ' it's a date
                    MonthString = MonthName(Month(cValue))
                    SubPathLevel2 = SubPathLevel1 & pSep & MonthString
                    If Len(Dir(SubPathLevel2, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then ' doesn't
                        MkDir SubPathLevel2
                        fCount = fCount + 1
                    'Else ' the folder already exists; do nothing
                    End If
                'Else ' it's not a date; do nothing
                End If
            Next r
        'Else ' the column range is empty; do nothing
        End If
    
    Next ws
    
    If fCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "All subfolders had already been created.", _
            vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
    Else
        MsgBox fCount & " subfolder" & IIf(fCount = 1, "", "s") & " created.", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    MsgBox "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description, vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was good, the problem was at the data in other word the excel value, in one of the cells of the entire column, there is a value that is not a date, i.e number or string, that's why it keeps returning an error.

```
If Not IsEmpty(xCellDate) And IsDate(xCellDate) Then
    xMonth = Month(xCellDate.Value)
    xMonthName = MonthName(xMonth)
    If Len(Dir((FPath & "\" & ws.Name & "\" & xMonthName), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
       MkDir (FPath & "\" & ws.Name & "\" & xMonthName)
    End If
End If
```